# FixedToolWindow border size

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I am being forced to update a VS2010 project to VS2013. One of the forms is a fixedtoolwindow, and is badly effected by the increase in width of the form's default borders.

FYI, all borders of the form have grown ~4 or 5 px. This is significant on my design for an embedded computer with a limited screen.

The 'Enable XP Visual Styles' checkbox has no effect on this problem.

Is there a simple way to retain the VS2010 visual style rather than modify the forms in this project?

Comment: This was not changed.  It isn't up to VS or .NET anyway. My crystal ball says that you also updated your dev machine to Windows 8 and did not actually check what happened on your embedded hardware.

Comment: The IT department did make some other changes to this system when VS2013 was installed, but our entire company is on the same version of Win7 and the project appears as-expected on my machine with VS2010. (Win8 is not allowed anywhere near our network.)

But you are spot-on correct that I have not yet tested this project on a target machine. I will get that done ASAP to verify the results.

Comment: I have loaded the software on the target computer, and it does, indeed, look correct.

Comment: Annnnnd i'm an idiot. Simply changing the Window7 desktop theme on the dev computer to a Window's classic style resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hans to pointing this in the right direction.

The entire problem was the windows theme on the development computer. The current theme is assumed by Visual Studio as the default for the target machine. Simply changing the development computer's theme to "Window's Classic" solved the issue.